# Format number with jquery numeric plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, numeric

I have some input with precompiled value from MySQL, I want to format and prevent from insert non numeric, I use the jQuery plugin [numeric](https://github.com/customd/jquery-number), but I have a problem:

```
<input type="text" value="0.826773" readonly="true" name="Efficienza" id="Efficienza" class="nogiallo float">
```

That is HTML code of my input and the function I call:

```
$(".float").number(true, 2,',','.' );
```

but the formatted number are `826.773,00`. But if I try

```
jQuery.number( $("#Efficienza").val(), 2, ',' , '.' );
```

it returns `0,83`.

Any suggestion or other plugin?

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: I expect 0,83  0 integer part 83 decimal part comma decimal separator dot miles separator on the second case if i parse the value of the Id imput it return the right value.